# Radiosity using a hemisphere

Tags: c++, shaders, hlsl, directx9

I'm working on a radiosity processor. I'm projecting scene geometry onto a hemisphere at a high order of tessellation during a visibility pass onto a 1024x1024 render target. The problem is that the edges of certain triangles are not being rendered to the item buffer( render target )...so when I test certain edges( or pixels during pixel shader ) for visibility during a reconstruction pass, visible edges are not identified and as a result the pixel for that edge is discarded.

One solution was to increase the resolution of the item buffer( up to 4096x4096 )...this helped and more edges were visible, however, this was not fullproof.

How do I increase visibility?

Here is a screenshot of a scene after radiosity is applied: the seams are edges along a triangle face that were not visible due to the resolution of the item buffer...
[image: Screenshot of a scene rendered w/radiosity]

fixed the problem by sampling the item buffer w/8 points:
[image: Screenshot of radiosity scene]

code to convert world space position into normalized device coordinates for uv lookup of item buffer:

```
// position lookup for item buffer
    Output.Pos3 = mul( Input.Position, mWV ); 
// projection is handled by normalizing the viewspace position( as i'm rendering to a hemisphere )
    Output.Pos3.xyz = normalize( Output.Pos3.xyz );

// convert to normalized device coordinates( [ -1, 1 ], [ -1, 1 ] -> [ 0, 1 ], [ 0, 1 ] )
    Output.Pos3.xy *= float2( 0.5, -0.5 );
    Output.Pos3.xy += float2( 0.5, 0.5 );
```

Comment: why do you need doubles in the first place? doubles perform poorly even on newer hardware.. and unless you are implementing an advanced geometric algorithm I see no reason to use them. maybe you can clarify ?

Comment: i'm implementing a radiosity processor...the visibility pass renders a 32bit address to an item buffer. I need to then render objects to the scene and sample the item buffer using the object's position( in normalized device coordinates ) in order to determine visibility. The problem is that I'm getting false positives because the position values sent to the pixel shader during rasterization are too close.

Comment: am not particularly sure that increasing the precision will solve the problem (maybe temporarly or for specific set).. but maybe you need to check where in the code you are losing precision ? maybe ins some sqrt calculations? or maybe your scene scale is just too small or too large..

Comment: @P.Avery The hardware isn't going to interpolate double-precision values from the vertex to the pixel properly anyway, so I don't think this approach can work for what you want to do.  Anyway, floats have precision of 1 in 2^24, so unless your scene is as big as a small country, I doubt float precision is really your problem.

Comment: @NathanReed I'm rendering visibility using a hemisphere. The problem I think is the resolution of the item buffer...when I increase resolution more of the edges that were not visible before are becoming visible( fixing some of the problems not all ). Is there anything else I can do to increase visibility? Hemicubes were too much hastle...I'm getting decent results this way and would like to continue using hemisphere...

Comment: seems to me like an epsilon if there is any intersection tests could solve the problem..

Comment: how do you mean?

Comment: @P.Avery How are you testing visibility?  The pixel positions in your hemispherical buffer are obviously not going to match exactly the positions you sample when drawing the eye view.  So your test needs to have tolerance for some error in the position.

Comment: i'm testing visibility by sampling an item buffer using normalized view space position coordinates...you're suggestion fixed the problem...i now sample from 9 points: the uv and the 8 points surrounding the uv...it works perfectly...thanks!

Comment: @P.Avery so did you use epsilon ?

Comment: @concept3d sort of...for each uv of the rasterized triangle i sampled 8 surrounding uvs...uv +- halfPixel

Comment: @concept3d what kind of intersection test did you have in mind?

Comment: @P.Avery I thought you were using different technique that require ray/tri intersection tests. because there is usually an error margin you need to take into account

Comment: @NathanReed i added code above that will convert the world space position of a vertex to normalized device coordinates to sample the item buffer with...I'm having trouble that is related to the position coordinates( converted to uvs ) as each triangle is rasterized...is there anything wrong with my conversion?